# How to test service layer which directly uses NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, testing, service

Hello can anyone give me advice on how to test my service layer which uses NHibernate `ISession` directly?

```
public class UserAccountService : IUserAccountService
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public UserAccountService(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public bool ValidateUser(string email, string password)
    {
        var value = _session.QueryOver<UserInfo>()
            .Select(Projections.RowCount()).FutureValue<int>().Value;

        if (value > 0) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I opt to use NHibernate directly for simple cases like simple query,validations and creating/updating records in the database. Coz i dont want to have an abstraction like repository/dao layer on top of Nhibernate that will just add more complexity to my architecture.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decide what you want to actually test on your Service Layer, regardless of the fact that you're using NH.

In your example, a good first test might be to test that the email and password that you pass into your service method is actually being used as a check in your session.

In this case, you'd simply need to stub your session variable and set up expectations using a mock framework of some kind (like Rhino Mocks) that would expect a pre-determined email and password, and then return an expected result.

Some pseudocode for this might look like:

```
void ValidateUser_WhenGivenGoodEmailAndPassword_ReturnsTrue()
{
  //arrange
  var stubbedSession = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISession>();

  stubbedSession
      .Expect(x => x.Query<UserInfo>())
      .Return(new List { 
          new UserInfo { Email = "johns@email.com", Password = "whatever" } });

  var service = new UserAccountService(stubbedSession);

  //act
  var result = service.ValidateUser("johns@email.com", "whatever");

  //assert
  Assert.That(result, Is.True);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find it difficult to test database interactions in a static way.  I'd recommend delegating responsibilities to another layer (that layer that adds complexity that you mentioned) that can be mocked for testing purposes, if you deem the functionality important enough to test.